Character Size Scaling After Coin Collection in Unreal Engine Blueprints
I want my character to grow by 10% after collecting each coin. The character should start at the default size and progressively increase in scale with each coin collected.

That sounds like an interesting goal. How have you tried achieving it so far, based on the available blueprint tutorials and documentation? What specific part are you currently stuck on?

The coin object collision, either the mesh(some meshes do not have simple collisions defined) or preferably a box collision component, should be set to the OverlapOnlyPawn preset.(All other components should be set to ignore all).
Make sure the Generate Overlap Events is checked on the collision component.
On component begin overlap  -> get world scale (input target from other on overlap node) then multiply the output (vector * float) with the fixed value of 1.1 for the float, -> set world scale  (input target from other on overlap node), value as the output of multiply.  -> Destroy Actor(self)

Note that 10% gain in size is exponential and will grow very large quickly.
